# Build Error with Parse iOS SDK and Facebook

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

I just created a new project and added a few pods as shown here:

```
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.4'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
    pod 'FacebookSDK'
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'Parse/FacebookUtils'
    pod 'Parse/TwitterUtils'
    pod 'Parse/UI'
end
```

I am OCCASIONALLY receiving this build error:

[image]

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_FBSDKSettings", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in PFFacebookPrivateUtilities.o
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o
objc-class-ref in PFFacebookPrivateUtilities.o
objc-class-ref in PFFacebookUtils.o
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am not sure why this "sometimes" happens, ir appears to show up when I change devices.  I mess around cleaning the project, do pod install, and then magically it works.

I know I must be missing something so if anyone has any advice they can give on how to troubleshoot or fix this issue I would appreciate it.

I have a very similar config running in other apps, but this time Parse, FB and others frameworks were updated... as well as Xcode.

Thanks for any help

Comment: good question, also interested in that one - did you find an answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to remove the `pod 'FacebookSDK'` from the Podfile, then it is installed automatically as dependency and for some reason it seems to work now

Answer (score 0):

That's an old issue, but still relevant today. These error messages are caused by `Parse/FacebookUtils` not linking the `FBSDKCoreKit` framework as dependency.

Basically any `Undefined symbol` are caused by a missing library or framework not being linked to the project/module.

https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1665